# Wordpress Image Crop Infinity

Tags: wordpress

When trying to crop an image in the Wordpress image editor and selecting a crop area: The buttons to save are greyed out and the selection properties, on the right, display "Infinity" in both fields.

[image: right after clicking edit image]

After rotating the image once (or multiple times) - is suddenly works correctly: Showing the right Selection Properties and the Save Button is working.

[image: After rotating]

I tried this with other images of lower resolutions as well - cropping never works right away.

Anyone experienced something similar?

Comment: I think this more suited to SuperUser

Answer (score 3):

Probably you added this (or a similar) line of code somewhere in your theme or plugin:

`setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE');`

The problem is that the crop function uses the decimal separator defined by the site language the first time. In German (and in a lot of other languages like Dutch, French and Spanish) this is a comma ',' instead of a dot '.'

You can fix this by adding this at the top of your functions.php file:

`setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'C');`

This will set the dot as a decimal separator, and make the crop function work immediately.

Source: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/with-some-solution-avatar-crop-error-in-spanishgermanitalianfrench-locale/

**-- EDIT --**

note that you probably should not use `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE');` anywhere in your theme in the first place. A valid reason why some people do use this is to get their date and time values in the correct format. In this case, replace the above code with: `setlocale (LC_TIME, 'de_DE');`

source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php#25041